# So confused, what is causing invalid syntax?

Tags: python

I copied following python from the instruction in the package:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud_fa import WordCloudFa

wordcloud = WordCloudFa().generate(' '.join(str(df[[df.labels == label].Body]))

image = wordcloud.to_image()
image.save('wordcloud.png')
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-52-b5ba472ed4a0>", line 6
    image = wordcloud.to_image()
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on the line *before* the error. Always look at the line before the error.

Comment: One closing ) too short in the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a parenthesis here

```
wordcloud = WordCloudFa().generate(' '.join(str(df[[df.labels == label].Body]))
```

it should be

```
wordcloud = WordCloudFa().generate(' '.join(str(df[[df.labels == label].Body])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a parethesis in here:

```
wordcloud = WordCloudFa().generate(' '.join(str(df[[df.labels == label].Body]))
```

it should be

```
wordcloud = WordCloudFa().generate(' '.join(str(df[[df.labels == label].Body])))
```

Probably you can benefit from using a text editor that helps you identify when you have a missing parenthesis or any other syntaxis issue.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out